# How to get original context after fn.call made?

Tags: javascript, function, oop, scope

I am using the "call" method to trigger a function and change the scope, but how do I get the original scope after doing this? In other words, how to access the "base" context?

For example, I am calling "joe" and passing "jill" as the context. However, in the 2nd alert in "greet", how do I access the "name: Joe" variable?

```
var joe = {  
    name : "Joe",  
    greet : function (name) {  
        alert(this.name + " says hello to " + name);  

        //Below is wrong. How do I get "Joe"?
        alert('Original Joe context name is: ' + this.name);
    }  
};  

var jill = {  
    name : "Jill"  
};  

//Outputs "Jill says hello to Mike"
joe.greet.call(jill, "Mike");
```

Here is a jsFiddle for this example: http://jsfiddle.net/ueeRk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot.

If you need it - pass it as a function argument.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "base" context. The `this` binding is determined dynamically on call time, it's not inherent to the function. There is no way to determine it from within the function, since functions don't have a "parent" object, and in fact they can be attached to multiple objects. As zerkms already said, if you need more information into the function, you have to pass it – or get it from an accessible scope, if available. For example, this would work:

```
alert('Original Joe context name is: ' + joe.name);
```